# how to instruct Git to warn me about deleted chunks?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, github-for-mac, atlassian-sourcetree

I work solo and commit changes by using Git to push changes to my repositories on BitBucket.org.

I'm paranoid that I might accidentally delete a bunch of lines from one of my files as I'm working. I work with a lot of files, and I don't usually look closely at Git diffs before committing changes.

I use GitHub for OSX to push changes, but I am open to using SourceTree instead. Can I instruct them to give me a warning if the newest version of a file contains more than, say, 10 deleted lines?

Comment: Just to understand your motivation: Why would it be bad if you deleted some lines? You could easily restore them from the history.

Comment: Give `git add -p` a try, and avoid `git commit -am` like the plague. I'm sure you will enjoy it!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No I couldn't - not if I never realized they were gone, which is the situation I'm trying to prevent.

Comment: OK. That sounds like a very strange scenario. Do you have gremlins on your computer? ;-) Or how else would code disappear without you realizing it?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Good question. I often cut and paste large blocks of text, move things around... Sometimes I delete org-mode headings and worry I may accidentally delete a subtree I haven't noticed...